# How to Register Application / Access Token for Magento Rest API

Tags: magento, rest-client

Here is my Consumer Info in Magento admin:

[image: Magento Consumer Screen]

I want to get an **Access Token** and **Access Token Secret**. How do I get it. I am looking to use [RestClient](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client).